# VS code version for CentOS 5 or 6?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Can I ask if there is a version of VS Code that works for CentOS 5 or 6? When trying installing VS, I encountered this error message

[image]

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: tried to `yum -y update glibc`?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately you cannot install VS Code on a CentOS 5 or 6 machine.  [The requirements](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/supporting/requirements) state that only CentOS 7 is supported due to the GLIBC issue you ran into above.